# White sauce with a deliberate raw-flour taste

Tags: sauce, flour

A local Chinese restaurant serves what they call Portuguese Chicken: a small casserole dish with a bed of rice, pieces of crispy-fried chicken, sauce, and a sprinkling of (Parmesan?) cheese, lightly browned in a hot oven or broiler.

The sauce is like a basic white-sauce, but yellow colored (I suspect turmeric), but rather than the usual creamy flour/butter taste, while it is still smooth and creamy, it has a noticeable raw flour flavour.

That raw flour taste actually goes quite well with this dish.

Is it simply under-cooked, or is there a special technique or name for this kind of sauce?

Comment: Off topic comment: While that dish description actually sounds delicious, it is nothing like I've ever heard of. I am Portuguese and never have I seen anything like that around here. Closest local dishes that remotely match your description are *Arroz de Pato* (Duck Rice) or *Empadão de Arroz* (Rice Casserole) both of which are made with a bed of rice layered with either shredded duck or ground beef, often with a gratin topping generally made of egg wash. No sauce or cheese to speak of.

Comment: Quick google search for [Rice Casserole](https://www.google.com/search?q=Rice+Casserole&tbm=isch) does seem to yield lots of results that seem to visually vaguely match your description of "yellow sauce"

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, as I said, it is a Chinese restaurant, so the Portuguese connection might be slim. (E.g. Hawai'ian Pizza is Canadian, Russian Dressing is American, Caesar Salad is Mexican, and Chicken Tikka Masala might be Scottish.)